# How to show only one installer ui when use bundle in wix v3.8?

Tags: user-interface, wix, bundle

I make a exe installer that include .net and msi with bundle of wix v3.8. The installer will show two UI that one is bundle and another is msi when installing. User Requirement is that the installer showing one UI. My code as followers:

```
<Chain>
  <ExePackage Id="DoNetFull" Name =".NET Framework 4.0 full runtime" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Vital="yes"  SourceFile="Resource\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
              InstallCommand="/q /norestart" Permanent="yes"  DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)">
    <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>
  </ExePackage>
  <MsiPackage Id="WinApp" Compressed="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" SourceFile="Resource\WinAppSetup.msi" Vital="yes" InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64"></MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

The DisplayInternalUI of MsiPackage must be set yes because of several interactive dialogs.How do i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a custom BA that shows only when you want it to. The default wixstdba will show UI through the whole installation process, although the MSI UI should show on top when it runs.

Update: You can find an example of a custom BA in the WiX toolset source code under `src\Setup\WixBA`. That's a WPF UI but you could use it to understand how to build your own custom solution.

Comment: It is difficult to understand that code for beginner. How to modify? Please give me help,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you can read about `silent install` here: 
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_directx9.htm 
 and also in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx